# if condition get skipped for calculating average in a loop based on some condition

Tags: java

I want to take the average while value in column A is lower than its next value and value in column B is the same as its next value. The average is taken from column C value based on column A value as column C index. Following is the data sample:

```
columnA,B,C
0,0,0.36
1,0,0.23
2,0,0.14
3,1,0.41
4,1,0.44
5,2,0.16
6,2,0.03
7,2,0.09
```

Following is my current code:

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public class dtw_post {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = 655;
        int x = 655;
        File file = new File("box_raw.txt");
        Scanner scannerFile = new Scanner(file);

         while(scannerFile.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scannerFile.nextLine();
                String[] lineVector = line.split(",");

        int a[] = new int[N];
        int b[] = new int[N];
        double c[] = new double[x];


        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        {
        a[i]=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0]);
        b[i]=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[1]);   
        c[i]=Double.parseDouble(lineVector[2]);
        }

        System.out.println((dtw_post.lookup(a,b,c)));}
        }

    static String lookup (int[] a, int[] b, double[] c){
        int j=0; int i=0;
        String[] final_result = new String[c.length];
        while(i < a.length-1){

        if (a[i] < a[i+1] && b[i] == b[i+1]) {
            double[] d = {c[a[i]],c[a[i+1]]};
            double sum = 0;
            int number = 0;
            for (double val : d) {
                ++number;
                sum += val;
            }
            double e = sum/number;
            final_result[i] = String.valueOf(e); 
            i++; 

        }
        else {
            final_result[i] = String.valueOf(c[a[i]]);
            i++;
        }
        }
        String result = final_result[j]; j++;
        return result;
    }
}
```

I expect it to output 0.243 in the first line as the average of 0.36,0.23,and 0.14. I figure that the problem is in the if condition in the lookup method. It seems to skip the if and run the else condition only. My current code output column C exactly as it is. What went wrong in my if condition loop? Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @kostek The question is *"Why did I get output Foo when I expected output Bar? Here is my code."* Vote accordingly, and leave useful comments if you have any.

Comment: "it seems to skip the if and run the else condition" is your condition inverted?

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is you are parsing the file wrong. You are parsing the file line by line in a while loop. But you are creating new `a`, `b` and `c` arrays for each line. Move the initialization out of the for loop :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = 655;
    int x = 655;

    int a[] = new int[N];
    int b[] = new int[N];
    double c[] = new double[x];
    int i = 0;

    File file = new File("box_raw.txt");
    Scanner scannerFile = new Scanner(file);

    while (scannerFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scannerFile.nextLine();
        String[] lineVector = line.split(",");

        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0]);
        b[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineVector[1]);
        c[i] = Double.parseDouble(lineVector[2]);
        ++i;
    }

    System.out.println((dtw_post.lookup(a, b, c)));
}
```

Based on that you will only get an average of two consecutive values. You also need to rethink the lookup function. Increase the sum until the value in `b` changes and then calculate the average and print it. E.g

```
static String lookup(int[] a, int[] b, double[] c) {

    String result = "";

    double sum = c[a[0]];
    int consecutive = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; ++i) {
        if (a[i - 1] < a[i] && b[i - 1] == b[i]) {
            sum += c[a[i]];
            ++consecutive;
        } else {
            result += String.valueOf(sum / consecutive) + '\n';
            sum = c[a[i]];
            consecutive = 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Ad a side note, you should also consider `StringBuilder` for concatenating strings in a loop

Answer (score 0):

In your if condition you required that a[i] is less than a[i+1], shouldn't it be a[i] greater than a[i+1]?

So the if should be:

```
if(a[i]>a[i+1] && b[i]==b[i+1]){
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are processing only one line of the file at a time.  The loop reads one line from the file and splits it to get values for a,b,c.  Then it copies these values into EVERY cell in the corresponding arrays, and then calls lookup.  Since every value of a is the same, if statement is never true.

What you want to do is fill in each successive cell in a,b,c with the next line read, and call lookup outside the while loop.  What I think you want is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = 655;
    File file = new File("box_raw.txt");
    Scanner scannerFile = new Scanner(file);

    int a[] = new int[N];
    int b[] = new int[N];
    double c[] = new double[N];

    int i = 0;
    while(scannerFile.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scannerFile.nextLine();
        String[] lineVector = line.split(",");

        a[i]=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0]);
        b[i]=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[1]);
        c[i]=Double.parseDouble(lineVector[2]);
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println((dtw_post.lookup(a,b,c)));
}
```